# Adding data to WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to add some data inside my DataGrid.

I added some columns with the designer. Now I want to add rows with data inside the DataGrid.

Here's my code so far:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dataContext = new PurchaseOrderDataContext();
    var purchaseOrderTable = dataContext.GetTable<PurchaseOrder>();

    var query = from a in purchaseOrderTable
            select a;

    var purchaseOrders = query;

    foreach (var purchaseOrder in purchaseOrders)
    {
        // I believe that this method is the right one, but what do I pass to it?
        // dataGrid1.Items.Add(test);
    }
}
```

All I want to know is: What kind of object do I need to use to add something in the DataGrid, and what kind of object do I need to pass to that last method? Also how do I add, let's say, text to a certain column of a row I added?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = query;
```

Comment: This works, but ideally if you set binding correctly to a proper source, this shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you would bind the ItemsSource of the grid to a collection that supports change notification (IObservableCollection is idea) and just add to the collection.  If the collection supports change notification, the grid will automatically display the new row.

Comment: I'm kind of a newbie with all that stuff, I used to do Mac Programming (Objective-C) so I'm kind of lost right now. I know that I can bind a collections to my ItemsSource. I tried here's what I did: I created SQL Database, linked it to my code with LINQ to SQL classes so now I can play with my database in the code. But in the designer when I try to bind my table to the DataGrid my collection isn't shown in the Binding panel (ItemsSource). Any idea or straightforward guide to this? Thanks very much.